# Can you use Firebase Analytics without Google Play Services installed?

Tags: firebase-analytics

I have been wrestling with Firebase Analytics and have managed to get a "Firebase app initialization successful". But I still get :

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Google Play services missing or without correct permission.
```

I have to install the app on a device that does not support Google Play Services (GPS), and is running Android Lollipop. I have followed [this guide](https://medium.com/@samstern_58566/how-to-use-firebase-on-android-without-the-google-services-plugin-93ecc7dc6c4) to avoid GPS, which hasn't worked. I do know that my setup works correctly, as I have successfully tested this on an Android emulator running GPS and Lollipop. So, is there a procedure for enabling Firebase Analytics without GPS ? Please link references that do not require GPS if you have them.